# What does 花つ月 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, kanji, archaic-language, old-japanese

> 緋【あか】色【いろ】の花【はな】つ月【づき】

I'm trying to figure out the meaning for this part of kanji in a title for a series. The red flower month? The red flower moon? The month of blossoming red flowers? I'm totally at a loss as to how to interpret 'はなつづき'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure つづき here is pun on the word 続き (sequel or continuation) and 月 (moon). The meaning would be something like "Month of red flowers", but with that added pun. (I think.)

Comment: @Eric Looks like [you're correct](http://www.st.rim.or.jp/~success/yayoi_ye.html) :)

Comment: You might know this, but it could be worth mentioning that つ is an old particle similar to の, linking 花 and 月.

Comment: adding ome examples : "沖つ白波", "まつげ" (目つ毛)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to a dictionary, [花つ月](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/178428/m0u/) is an alternative name for *March*, the third month of the year in the traditional Japanese calendar. (I didn't know that.)

So 緋色の花つ月 means *March in Crimson* or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

The Crimson "month of flowers".  Or Crimson March.