# What is つ in 中つ国 and why is it equivalent to の?

Tags: archaic-language, old-japanese

According to Wikipedia:

> 中つ国（なかつくに）とは中間の国、中央の国を意味し、「つ」は現代語の「の」に相当する。中津国、中国とも書く。

I looked for 津 in a dictionary but it seems to be an 当て字 so I did not get new information. But I can't get why の was not used in place of つ (since つ and の seems to be equivalent here). Indeed, の is a very old word, why つ has been preferred? What are the nuances that つ conveys and の does not?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23526/5010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

つ is just an [older version of the particle の](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A4). Its use here, assuming that you are referring to Tolkien's Middle-earth, is literary and adds an older and more mystical flavor in the same way that using a lot of older words of English origin might.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to Tolkien's Middle-earth. I definitively should have checked a kobun dictionary. Thank you.